# Specialized reduce/fold methods for specific element types

Tags: types, jvm, api-design, language-design

Most language APIs these days offer ways to fold or reduce iterables (or observables) into a single element. For example, in the [Xtend](https://www.eclipse.org/xtend/) "dialect" of Java I could fold a set of elements into a single lop-sided binary tree like this:

```
val Set<?> items = #{"A", 42, true, #{}}
val tree = items.reduce[#[$0, $1]]
```

I have to tell the `reduce` method exactly how I would like to combine the intermediate reduction result with the next element (in this contrived and meaningless example, they are combined into a list of two elements, which always works even if I don't know the type of the elements).

Many data types have one or more "inner" operations that might frequently be used in a fold/reduce context. For example, strings have a concatenation operation, or integers have a sum and a product operation.

In a JVM-based language that I'm currently developing, I would like to support such specialized "concatenation", "sum" or "product" operations if an iterable has the required element type. For example, in Xtend, I could write:

```
interface IntegerIterable extends Iterable<Integer>
{
    def Integer sum()
    {
        reduce[$0 + $1]
    }
    
    def Integer product()
    {
        reduce[$0 * $1]
    }
}
```

The problem is that these methods would only be available on actual `IntegerIterable` objects, but not on any `Iterable<Integer>`. I would like the `sum` and `product` methods to be available on any `Iterable` that has an `Integer` element type. Similarly, I would expect a `concatenation` method on any `List<String>`, etc.

I could imagine defining a "pseudo-type" `List<Integer>` (or `Iterable<Integer>`) that would offer the additional methods as extension methods if the element type matches.
The language I'm working on is JVM-based and somewhat Java-like, but I'm curious how this sort of problem is solved in other languages (I imagine, that, as usual, Haskell probably has a nifty way of achieving this?). I am aware of the technique of wrapping elements in a semigroup (or monoid) to combine the data with an operation (to be using for folding/reducing), but I'm specifically interested in solutions that do not require such a wrapper for the individual elements.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said “somewhat Java-like” let’s use Java as starting point. For an interface like

```java
public interface Iterable<T> {
    Iterator<T> iterator();

    default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(action);
        for(T t: this) {
            action.accept(t);
        }
    }

    default Optional<T> reduce(BinaryOperator<T> op) {
        Iterator<T> i = iterator();
        if(!i.hasNext()) return Optional.empty();
        T t = i.next();
        while(i.hasNext()) t = op.apply(t, i.next());
        return Optional.of(t);
    }
}
```

you can also write the `reduce` method like

```java
default Optional<T> reduce(Iterable<T> this, BinaryOperator<T> op) {
    Iterator<T> i = iterator();
    if(!i.hasNext()) return Optional.empty();
    T t = i.next();
    while(i.hasNext()) t = op.apply(t, i.next());
    return Optional.of(t);
}
```

This syntax has been introduced to support annotations on the receiver type. But it it’s easy to imagine an extension for the methods you have in mind, e.g.

```java
default Integer sum(Iterable<Integer> this) {
    return reduce(Integer::sum).orElse(0);
}
```

This is not legal Java with the `Iterable<T>` type above, but could be in your own language. The meaning should be clear: this method is only available if the invocation receiver type is assignable to `Iterable<Integer>`. The declaration itself should be constrained to subtypes of the declaring type, so you can’t declare a method that is impossible to ever be available.

This would be the solution with the least deviation from Java. It wouldn’t even be a new syntax.

Comment: Ah, that's clever, I hadn't thought about using something like Java's receiver type notation for this, but that would certainly work. My only concern is that putting these methods on the container type itself introduces a certain amount of coupling, i.e. it only works if I control the source code for that type

Comment: Yes, with this syntax the declaration has to be in the type itself. For extension methods, you definitely need a new syntactic element, as Java doesn’t have them. But this could be as simple as a keyword, e.g. `extension Integer sum(Iterable<Integer> this) { return reduce(Integer::sum) .orElse(0); }`, still using the receiver type notation to describe the applicable targets.